Is it better to pass AppLocalizations as a parameter or read it from context?
The other day at work we got into this discussion when Copilot was giving different answers for similar questions.
The discussion was: if I have multiple children that use AppLocalizations, should I read it from context in a common parent's build method and send that instance to each one of the children or get it from context inside each widget?
In other words, between the two options:
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ParentWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    return Column(children: [
      Text(localizations.someLabel),
      ChildWidget(localizations: localizations),
    ]);
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final AppLocalizations localizations;

  const ChildWidget({required this.localizations, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(localizations.someOtherLabel);
  }
}

and
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ParentWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    return Column(children: [
      Text(localizations.someLabel),
      const ChildWidget(),
    ]);
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChildWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    return Text(localizations.someOtherLabel);
  }
}

which one is more acceptable?
(Probably a matter of opinion, but it doesn't hurt to ask)

Option 1 is preferable in scenarios where performance is critical, or you have many children that need access to the same localization data. It can also be beneficial in a clean architecture context, where managing shared resources from a higher level makes sense.
Option 2 is actually more suitable for simpler scenarios or when you want each widget to be self-contained and easier to test independently.
